# Flutter package get: not working

Tags: git, dart, flutter

i think it might be a problem with my specific flutter tho im not sure, i will be glad to get help!
I tried to run a simple `firebase_auth: ^0.5.5` on my `dependencies:` in that order: `dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    firebase_auth: ^0.5.5`

but i get this string in the Debug Console:

```
[login_register_3] flutter packages get
fatal: bad config line 1 in file .git/config
Updating flutter tool...

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Failed to send crash report. Server responded with HTTP status code 400
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'environment' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: environment
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/dart:core/object_patch.dart:46)
#1      AndroidWorkflow.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:79)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:71)
#3      Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:128)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _doctorText.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:237)
#5      AppContext._run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:76)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      AppContext.runInZone.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:66)
#7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#8      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#9      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
#10     AppContext.runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:65)
#11     _doctorText (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:237)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     _createLocalCrashReport (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:212)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:167)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:94)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     AppContext._run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:76)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     AppContext.runInZone.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:66)
#17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#19     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
#20     AppContext.runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:65)
#21     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:61)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:48)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     main (file:///c:/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:16)
#24     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:277)
#25     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:165)
exit code 255
```

Now, this error accoures each time i try to run a flutter package even `$ flutter doctor`, so i dont know where to pin the problem at! Much apparition in advanced

Comment: Were you able to run your code before? I think your flutter is broken. I'd try to remove it and install again

Comment: I think that you should just reinstall Git and maybe Flutter, put the necessary path variables and everything should be fine again.

Answer (score 2):

Write the package in the same alignment to other packages and use this code, to get packages.

```
flutter packages get
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem about your project or flutter git config. You can look this reply for this station.

> For those hitting into this issue (I believe it's due to crashing out
>   git mid init?) in windows, if you have a recent backup of the config
>   file from your git repo's .git/ folder you can fix it by replacing the
>   existing with it (any ref's added since the copy will obviously need
>   re-adding) - not at all ideal but better than loosing all the commits.

Comment: could you be more specific please? i'm fairly new to flutter or coding in general i'm and i know what you are referring to as the problem, tho im not sure how to solve it on my own. this is my email if you care help me with all the technical specifics yoavg111@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Run ***flutter packages get*** from flutter terminal